# ImportError: libblas.so.3

Tags: python-2.7, turi

After installation of turicreate, when I am importing it

```
import turicreate
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/papun/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/turicreate/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from turicreate.data_structures.sgraph import Vertex, Edge
  File "/home/papun/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/turicreate/data_structures/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from . import sframe
  File "/home/papun/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/turicreate/data_structures/sframe.py", line 16, in <module>
    from ..connect import main as glconnect
  File "/home/papun/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/turicreate/connect/main.py", line 13, in <module>
    from ..cython.cy_unity import UnityGlobalProxy
ImportError: libblas.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

It will helpful, if I can get a suggestion on this. I have also tried
re installing scipy.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install Blas.

Follow instruction details in this blog: [libblas and liblapack issues and speed, with SciPy and Ubuntu](http://danielnouri.org/notes/2012/12/19/libblas-and-liblapack-issues-and-speed,-with-scipy-and-ubuntu/)

Comment: Thanks , I had checked that earlier. I am using Ubuntu 15.04.                        Executing sudo apt-get install libatlas3-base as described there is giving me            
E: Unable to locate package libatlas3-base